# How to group filter options by nested property of a collection. Single checkbox

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm wondering how can I group the filter values of a column by a property field of a collection.

The column data:

```js
{ 
  users: [
    {id: 1, isExternal: true, name: "John" }, 
    {id: 2, isExternal: false, name: "George"},
    {id: 3, isExternal: true, name: "Bob"}
  ]
}
```

The external users are formatted by a valueGetter function:

```js
columnDefs: [
  {
    enableRowGroup: true,
    field: "users",
    headerName: "Users",
    minWidth: 150,
    filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
    valueGetter: (params: any) => {
      return (params.data.users || []).map((user: User) =>
        user.isExternal ? `${user.name} (EXT)` : user.name
      );
    }
  }
];
```

I ended up having the column filter with many checkboxes of each value.

Would it be possible to group the filter items into 1 checkbox?

For example: a checkbox filter named "External", where it would filter in all external users and  when unchecked, it would display all users.

Comment: do you have the id of the user on the params argument of the valueGetter function?

Comment: Yes, all the fields I can retrieve from params.data.users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a custom filter to achieve that.

[How to build a custom filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/)

Accordingly to this doc, you need to build two components:

- the actual filter component, who checks if the column data have the correct value
- a "floating filter", in the case that you want to use this filter
  behind the header of the column

The floating filter calls the logic in the "main" filter and updates the view in the table.

For the main filter, the code could be like this:

```
     @Component(  selector: 'app-boolean-filter',
                         template: '
<div class="ag-filter">
   <select [(value)]="currentFilterValue" (change)="filterChange($event.target.value)">
      <option value="">all values</option>
      <option value="true">yes</option>
      <option value="false">no</option>
   </select>
</div>',
      style: '.ag-filter {  
        width: 100%;
        select {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 24px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding-left: 6px;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #babfc7;
        }
    }')
    
    export class BooleanFilterComponent implements IFilterAngularComp {
      currentFilterValue: any;
    
      private params: IFilterParams;
      private valueGetter: (rowNode: RowNode) => any;
    
      agInit(params: IFilterParams): void {
        this.params = params;
        this.currentFilterValue = null;
        this.valueGetter = params.valueGetter;
      }
    
      isFilterActive(): boolean {
        return this.currentFilterValue !== null;
      }
    
      doesFilterPass(params: IDoesFilterPassParams): boolean {
        const valueGetter: any = this.valueGetter;
        const value: any = valueGetter(params);
    
        if (this.isFilterActive()) {
          return value === JSON.parse(this.currentFilterValue);
        }
      }
    
      getModel(): any {
        return this.isFilterActive() ? this.currentFilterValue : null;
      }
    
      setModel(model: any): void {
        this.filterChange(model);
      }
    
      afterGuiAttached(params: IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void {
      }
    
      takeValueFromFloatingFilter(value: any): void {
        this.filterChange(value);
      }
    
      filterChange(newValue: any): void {
        this.currentFilterValue = newValue === '' ? null : newValue;
        this.params.filterChangedCallback();
      }
    }
```

The **doesFilterPass** method is where the magic hapens: the **valueGetter(params)**, gets the value from the data field that you configure in the grid column and checks if it passes the filter, hidding or showing it in the table.

Comment: It worked, thank you! 
However, is there a way to filter the elements inside the cell? 
Note that each cell contains an array of Users. 
If I would select "External" from the dropdown, it filters all records that have external users (already working after your answer), but also I would like to filter the values inside each cell. Something like a dynamic valueGetter according to the selected filter option.

Comment: You can implement a customCellRenderer to show filtered data in the cell. In the "params" object, you can read the applied filters calling params.api.
more info:  https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Comment: Thank you so much!